# Ffmpeg concat audio without spaces between

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concat a few m4a audio files, seems like everything works fine.

I'm using such command `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -y -af anlmdn output.m4a`

I've noticed that im getting space between audio [image: Spaces between audios]

Maybe someone knows how to remove these spaces and make concatenating each entry after each

Comment: Which codec, sampling rate for the audio?

Comment: Sample Rate = 44100. AUDIO ENCODER = AAC @Gyan.

Comment: Add `inpoint 0.2323` on a new line after each file entry in the text file, starting with the 2nd file entry.

Comment: @Gyan thanks. Actually, I have a suspicion, that something with the recording. Coz first part also has a small space at the beginning.

Comment: Those are priming samples. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42410479/

Comment: @Gyan Great, thanks. I will remove all these samples.

Comment: @DmytroFilipenko so how to remove spaces between audio(s) after concat them with ffmpeg??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ffmpeg loads an AAC stream, it internally adds an extra 2 frames of silence for padding, often called "priming samples." The comment above that says to add an inpoint of 0.2322 is correct for a specific sample rate, though there's more to do if you want it to be perfectly seamless.

To concat seamlessly with no gaps, you can do the following:

1. Calculate the AAC frame length based on the sample rate, e.g. 1024/44100 = 0.02321995 for 44.1KHz.
2. Encode an extra 2 AAC frames at the beginning and end of each segment.
3. Account for the 2 silent padding frames that ffmpeg always adds internally.
4. Assign inpoint and outpoint directives in the concat txt file so that only the "good" content is used when creating the output file.

The 2 extra beginning frames are required because each AAC frame is dependent on up to 2 frames before it. So to encode the first frame correctly, it needs that context. The 2 extra frames at the end are required because ffmpeg tapers the audio at the end to avoid a sudden pop. By adding 2 extra frames, we shift the taper so it doesn't affect our actual content. These extra frames are then removed with inpoint and outpoint to avoid repeated content.

Using this method, it's important that all segments have a length that's an exact multiple of an AAC frame duration. If they don't, you will see unpredictable artifacts at segment boundaries.

I recently released a repo that demonstrates this further with actual code: https://github.com/wistia/seamless-aac-split-and-stitch-demo.